# Voila Dashboard base url

Tags: jupyter, voila

When running voila my_notebook.ipynb, voila starts properly and the dashboard is displayed. When setting the base url (with --Voila.base_url='/my-base-url'):

- A `403: Forbidden` error is shown in the browser
- A `WARNING:tornado.general:403 GET /test/voila/files/test (::1): File not whitelisted` warning is received in the terminal.

Adding the `--VoilaConfiguration.file_whitelist="['.*']"` argument to the voila command results in:

- `404: Not Found` in the browser
- `WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /test/voila/files/test (::1) 1.38ms` in terminal

In my understanding specifying the base-url as '/my-base-url' should make the dashboard available at `localhost:8866/my-base-url`. Is this how it should work or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2):

the base url indicates the folder where your notebook is located, you'll still need to use localhost:8866/my-base-url/name-of-your-notebook-file